# In result output, Additional rows for NA is showing

Tags: r

I'm learning R and there is one issue I am facing while running the code. I wrote the code to get the data for `NY` (New York). But some additional rows as complete `NA`s is showing up. Please help.

```
Dummy Data:
ID   Name   Industry Inception Employees  State   City    Revenue    Expenses
1 Over-Hex Software   2006      25       TN    Franklin  9,684,527  1,130,700 
2 Unimattax  IT       2009      36        NY   New York  14,016,543   804,035 
3 Greenfax Retail     2012      NA        SC   Greenville 9,746,272 1,044,375 
4 Blacklane  IT      2011       66       NY   New York  15,359,369  4,631,808
```

Result output:

```
2 Unimattax  IT       2009      36        NY   New York  14,016,543   804,035 
NA  <NA>     <NA>       NA       NA       <NA>     <NA>       NA         NA
4 Blacklane  IT      2011       66       NY   New York  15,359,369  4,631,808
NA  <NA>     <NA>       NA       NA       <NA>     <NA>       NA         NA

fin[fin$State == "NY",] # fin is the table name
```

Comment: Try with `fin[fin$State == "NY" & !is.na(fin$State),]` or use `fin[fin$State %in% "NY",]`

Comment: you can use subset also in this case fin <- subset(fin, State == "NY")

Comment: Hi! welcome to SO! It is great that you provided dummy data. The next time, I'd advise you to put the result of `dput(<yourdataframe>)`. This way, people can just copy&paste your example data :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with having `NA` elements in 'State' which will result in `NA` when we do the `==`.  To avoid that, create an `&` expression with `is.na` to make those NA elements to FALSE.

```
fin[fin$State == "NY" & !is.na(fin$State),]
```

Or another option is `%in%`, that generates FALSE for `NA`

```
fin[fin$State %in% "NY",]
```